# initialize std::list::iterator object created with malloc throwing exception

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, initialization, malloc

Why is this code throwing an exception?

It only happens when iterator array is created with malloc.
(I know I can use vectors and fix it but just curious to know the reason)

```
int count = 100;
std::list<std::wstring>::iterator* its = (std::list<std::wstring>::iterator*)malloc(sizeof(std::list<std::wstring>::iterator)*count);
std::list<std::wstring> list;
list.push_back(L"aaa");
list.push_back(L"bbbb");
std::list<std::wstring>::iterator it;
// no exception
it=list.begin();
//read access denied 
its[0] = it;
```

I know that malloc doesn't call the constructor object, but here 
the copy contractor should be called in the last line, as far as I know the copy constructor should not have anything to do with previous initialization, correct me if I'm wrong

I'm not using "new " because I want an array of objects

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `malloc` doesn't actually create anything.  You need to use placement new to actually put a object in that memory, or just get rid of `malloc` and use `new` to begin with.  Or, even better, don't use either and just have a `std::list<std::wstring>::iterator`

Comment: @NathanOliver edited the question

Comment: *as much as i know copy contractor should not have anything to do with previous initialization , correct me if i'm wrong* This is incorrect.  The constructor is only ever called when using placement new, or when first declaring the object.  `it=list.begin();` is assignment and you can't assign to an object that has not be constructed.

Comment: If you want an array of iteratos, use `auto its = std::vector<std::list<std::wstring>::iterator>(count);`

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you but as mentioned in question i know i can use vectors , actually i asked the question wrongly i  should had asked "why the copy constructor of iterator not working here", not looking for solution , just looking for the reason

Comment: A copy constructor is only called when you do something like `T foo = some_T_object;` or `T foo(some_T_object)`

Comment: @NathanOliver ok sorry for my mistake , i read in [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/begin/) (the documentation of std::list) in the Exception safety session  :: <<No-throw guarantee: this member function never throws exceptions.
The copy construction or assignment of the returned iterator is also guaranteed to never throw.>>  it indcates the assignment  should njnot throw exceptions ,, so the question :: does assigning its[0] to list.begin() has anything to do with the bytes in raw memory ? i thought they should be overwrited without the previous values being read in here

Comment: That's not how C++ works.  If there is not a object there, then it's undefined behavior and anything can happen, like gettting an exception.  This is why the advice is just don't use malloc in C++.  It doesn't play well with classes at all.

Comment: @NathanOliver got it, thanks for helping